# How does crypto kitties lists their auctions?

Tags: mapping, cryptokitties

Crypto Kitties offers a marketplace where you can buy kitties. The functionality is handeled by a contract called `SaleClockAuction`. This contract inherits from `ClockAuctionBase` where all auctions are stored in a mapping `mapping (uint256 => Auction) tokenIdToAuction;` The only way to get an auction seems to be the function `getAuction(uint256 _tokenId)`.

If I want a list of all auctions would mean I had to iterate over all kitties and call `getAuction(uint256 _tokenId)` for each kitty to check if an auction exists.

Question is: Is this really the way to do it or am I missing something here?

https://github.com/dapperlabs/cryptokitties-bounty/tree/master/contracts/Auction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch all the `AuctionCreated` events (it's in `ClockAuctionBase.sol` which `SaleClockAuction` indirectly inherits from) which are created when auctions are created.

Comment: OK so I have fetch all `AuctionCreated` event and all `AuctionClosed` to get a list of all running auctions. I'm wondering if this couldn't cause performance issues with an increasing number of auctions and using a client like `Metamask` to access the blockchain. Crypto kitties offers a api function on their webserver to fetch all running auctions. So maybe they are caching this information on their server.